# How to Call Function inside Array

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, return-type, custom-function

I will create a json file with PHP with json_encode. I intend to include a function that I will call inside array before I change it to json. Whether calling functions inside an array can be done?

```
$arrayList = array( 
                array( 
                'uid' => "1234",
                'nilai' => getBoolean (1)));                
function getBoolean ($value) {
    if ($value == 0 ) {
        echo "false";
    } else {
        echo "true";
    }   
}
echo json_encode ($arrayList);
```

Output json

```
true[{"uid":"1234","nilai":null}]
```

What if I want json output like below

```
[{"uid":"1234","nilai":true}]
```

So the value of the function (getBoolean) goes into json not outside. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP uses an [applicative order evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Applicative_order) so `getBoolean(1)` will be evaluated *before* the array is assigned to `$arrayList`.

However, you have a bug in your `getBoolean` function. You need to `return` a boolean type value, not the string version of the boolean.

Code: (https://3v4l.org/AOdn3B)

```
$arrayList = [ [ 'uid' => '1234', 'nilai' => getBoolean (1) ] ];

function getBoolean ($value) {
    return (bool) $value;
}

echo json_encode ($arrayList);
```

Output:

```
[{"uid":"1234","nilai":true}]
```

---

p.s. I wouldn't personally bother to write a custom function for this.  Just prepend `(bool)` directly to your array value.

```
$arrayList = [ [ 'uid' => 1234, 'nilai' => (bool) 1 ] ];
```

Then again if you have negative numbers or some other fringe case, use:

```
if ($value == 0) {
    return false; // boolean, not string
} else {
    return true; // boolean, not string
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked, I'm just trying to give a string value, so it's not real boolean hehe..